# Substitute a button for a timed event?

Tags: timer, button

Disclaimer: I am a total newbie

I have something I bought that once is switched on does something each time I press a button, now, I want that to happen periodically(no accuracy needed) so I was thinking on substituting that button for something.

Is there any simple thing I could put there which would give me a periodic "button press"? Doesn't need to be accurate and I would be thinking on ranges from 5 secs to 30 secs, but anything is acceptable really, I would prefer non-ic alternatives.

Basically I want to swap something like this:

[image: this]

with a timed "push event"

Comment: Can you be more specific about the thing ?

Comment: You will need to give us a lot more details. Is this button NO or NC? What voltages are used on it, is there a pull up/down resistor? Why no ICs? I think you are still very much in the brainstorming stage and haven't done enough research on your own to create a good question.

Comment: Kellenjb, I have no idea yet what the voltage is and not sure how to find NO/NC, I will try to extract that info from the device I have.

Comment: I vote for the mechanical approach: a motor geared down with a cam attached to the shaft that pushes your button every time it makes a full rotation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's wrong with ICs now??

Anyway, what you want is a astable multivibrator, which is often made with an LM555 (IC!), but you can also make it with a pair of discrete transistors:

[image]

The period T = time the button is pressed (t1) + time between button presses (t2), where

t1 = 0.69 \$\times\$ C1 \$\times\$ R3, and
t2 = 0.69 \$\times\$ C2 \$\times\$ R2

Use the output to drive a reed relay via another transistor. Place contacts of the reed relay parallel to your button. If a contact resistance of a few tens of ohms is OK (the reed relay will be milli-ohms) you can use a [74HC4066](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/74HC_HCT4066.pdf) as the switch. But then we're again using an IC...

Comment: what did u use to draw that? looks cool

Comment: @ArkaitzJimenez: found it [here](http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/waveforms/astable.html). Excellent site, by the way.

Answer (score -1):

A microcontroller or FPGA could do this trivially. You would just need to put a loop counter and raise/lower the output at the desired times.

Comment: Or a whole PC :-)

Comment: Or a servant :-(

Comment: Why the down vote? He wants something automatic to simulate pressing a button and either of these could.

Comment: I didn't downvote.

Comment: The servant fits the requirements, as it's a non-IC solution, and will probably not be accurate. Most FPGAs are ICs.

Comment: @Brian: I didn't downvote, though I don't think it's a good answer. You should give more details of how you solve this using a microcontroller.

Answer (score -1):

Sounds a little like a time delay relay.  They come with lots of different options, but here's an example:

http://www.smarthome.com/7279/Delay-Timer-Relay-ELK-960/p.aspx

Comment: Can you give some more details in your answer? As it is now you are just recommending a consumer product where as you should be answering an actual electrical engineering question. That product is a circuit board and all, but it is specially designed to be used in smarthome applications which I consider to be consumer electronics

Comment: Still needs a pushbutton, and only gives 1 pulse, not something periodical.